# Updating Datagrid After Query in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am trying to get into better programming habits so I've been working my way through various `MVVM` examples.

In this app I have got one view.  I want this to take user's chosen selection from combo boxes (for now this is hard coded) and update a datagrid with the selected results after running an `SQL` query.

So far I am able to get the first lot of results on creation of the `ResultViewModel` (`using LoadResults();`) but when I run the next SQL query (`using OnUpdate();`) the `datagrid` does not update with the results (I've checked that the query runs fine with debugging).

I think I've missed something when going from one tutorial to another.  I have a feeling I may need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `ResultViewModel` but I've tried implementing it and couldn't get it to work.

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**ResultModel**

```
public class ResultModel { }

public class Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string theHomeTeam;
    private string theVisitorTeam;


    public string HomeTeam
    {
        get { return theHomeTeam; }

        set
        {
            if (theHomeTeam != value)
            {
                theHomeTeam = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("HomeTeam");
            }
        }
    }

    public string VisitorTeam
    {
        get { return theVisitorTeam; }

        set
        {
            if (theVisitorTeam != value)
            {
                theVisitorTeam = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("VisitorTeam");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

}
```

**ResultViewModel.cs**

public class ResultViewModel
    {

```
    public ObservableCollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

    private Result _selectedResult;

    public MyICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
    public MyICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    public MyICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

    public ResultViewModel()
    {
        LoadResults("Liverpool", "Everton");
        DeleteCommand = new MyICommand(OnDelete, CanDelete);
        SaveCommand = new MyICommand(OnSave, CanSave);
        UpdateCommand = new MyICommand(OnUpdate, CanUpdate);
    }


    public void LoadResults(string theHomeTeam, string theVisitorTeam)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Result> results = new ObservableCollection<Result>();

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureCon"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT * FROM tblEnglishLeagueResults WHERE elrHomeTeam = '" + theHomeTeam + "' AND elrVisitorTeam = '" + theVisitorTeam + "';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Results");
            sda.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                results.Add(new Result { HomeTeam = Convert.ToString(row[3]), VisitorTeam = Convert.ToString(row[4]) });
            }

        }
        Results = results;
    }

    public Result SelectedResults
    {
        get { return _selectedResult; }
        set
        {
            _selectedResult = value;
            DeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool CanDelete() { return SelectedResults != null; }

    private void OnDelete() { Results.Remove(SelectedResults); }

    private bool CanUpdate() { return true; }

    private void OnUpdate() { LoadResults("Liverpool", "Sunderland"); }

    private bool CanSave() { return true; }

    private void OnSave() { //SAVE LOGIC}
```

}

**ResultView.xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Results, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=HomeTeam}" Header="Home Team"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=VisitorTeam}" Header="Visitor Team"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel

```
public class ResultViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And add a notification to the view for your List:

```
private ObservableCollection<Result> _Results;

public ObservableCollection<Result> Results 
{
    get { return this._Results; }

    set
    {
        this._Results= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Results");           
    }
}
```

Comment: And just like that it works.  Thank-you very much!  You've saved me a lot of time trying to find the answer in the depths of the internet.

Comment: Happy to help, the change is in your Results, and Results property is in you ViewModel, how would the view know about the change if you don't notify it ? Answer is INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM.

Comment: Makes sense.  A good lesson learned and another step forward on the MVVM journey.  Thanks again.